# content.ts file not building when I run "npm run build"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, react-typescript, npm-scripts, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm a complete beginner at creating Chrome extensions. So far, I've been able to create a basic popup but when I try to add my content.ts file to add some functionality, it displays an error message upon reloading the extension.

I'm just completely lost on how to fix this and I couldn't find anything online either. Asked ChatGPT and it didn't really give anything helpful. Any help would be appreciated!

I added this line to my manifest.json file so that it could recognise the content script file:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["chrome/content.js"]
  }
]
```

and reloaded the extension. Then, I was going to check if the extension was working, but it displayed this error message:

```
Error
Could not load JavaScript 'chrome/content.js' for content script.
Could not load manifest.
```

I've tried this several times, with different templates that also provide webpack configurations. This also led to the same conclusion.

Comment: It means the path in `js` is incorrect. If content.js is in the same folder as manifest.json in the output directory then the path should be "content.js"

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi, thanks for the reply! My manifest.json file is in the public directory and the content.ts file is in the src/chrome directory. I realised I wrote it wrong in the section I gave above, so I rewrote it as "src/chrome/content.js" but this still gives me the same error: 
"Error
Could not load JavaScript 'src/chrome/content.js' for content script."

Comment: You need to look in the **output** directory e.g. dist or build, because this is what the browser uses.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am clicking on the build directory when I press "Load unpacked" but I'm not really sure what to look for to see that the content.ts file is being built. I had an issue where it told me I couldn't compile the file since it's considered a global script file so I put "export {}" at the top of the file. I'm not really sure what to look for in the build/static/js directory since all the .js files have names along the lines of "main.e4dc14dd.js".

Comment: Look at content.js in the output directory and use its relative path there in manifest.json. If you don't have any then your build config is incorrect and you need to define an entry for the content script.